# What is the most fundamental syntactic unit?

Tags: syntax

If you were to attempt to define the rules of the grammar of a language, what would be the lowest level “unit” of syntax of which every valid utterance is some subtype?

Answer (score 2):

I think that phrase structure grammar assumed a symmetry or regularity in that all the fundamental units of syntax were phrases. SP’s are made of NP’s and VP’s; etc. It probably seemed theoretically self-consistent to have one unifying concept for all components of the sentence, and the sentence seemed like the top-most element.

But the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language says that the fundamental unit of syntax is the clause, not the sentence, and that sentences are not a type of clause.

The grammar provides no explicit definition of “sentence” because it’s not part of their theory of syntax. Instead, what are commonly called sentences may be either **clauses** - *Kim likes beer* - or **coordinated clauses** - *Kim likes beer and she runs*. These two terms are not unified by some higher category. They are the top level. Which means that the clause, as the unit in which the rest is defined in relation to, have both a substructure and a superstructure.

By observation, five types of clauses are identified: declarative, closed and open interrogative, exclamative and imperative.

Each has its own “characteristic use” and a number of particular grammatical properties.

Answer (score 1):

In the Minimalist approach, the *most* fundamental unit is "the set". An utterance may contain only one set ("Yes"), or three ("good boy" – the sets "good" and "boy" which merge into one set). To this, you can add "categories" like "noun", "verb", etc. and eventually you can arrive at groupings like "NP", "DP" and so on.

An alternative way of interpreting your question is whether there is some one node-type that is present in every grammatical derivation. That presupposes that there is a universal set of categories (not universally assumed, and the content of which is almost universally variable amongst practitioners who hold to a universal list of categories). The other problem is that "utterance" is really not a unit of syntax, it is a unit of human behavior. Thus "cat" is (can be) an utterance, but not necessarily a "valid syntactic unit". A speaker may be able to utter a fragment of a word, like "ish", but that does not mean that the grammar of the language generates that output (unless you insist that all speaker behavior has to be generated by the grammar).